# How to mock a retrofit service observable calling onError?

Tags: unit-testing, mockito, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-android

I am testing this code.

```
service.getProducts()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<Result<Catalog<SoajsProductPreview>>>() {

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    view.showErrorView(e);
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Result<Product>  products) {
                   view.showProducts(products)
                }

                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {}
            });
```

Testing that `view.showProducts()` the mocked service returns results works fine.
I do

```
when(service.getProducts().thenReturn(someObservable);
```

Now I want to test that `view.ShowErrorView()` is called when the service throws an error but I can't find a way to do that:

Obviously the following doesn't compile

```
when(service.getProducts().thenReturn(someException);
```

And this throws an exception immediately but doesn't call the Subscriber's `onError` method

```
when(service.getProducts().thenReturn(someException);
```

How can I get `Subscriber.onError()` called?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
when(service.getProducts().thenReturn(Observable.error(someException))
```

should work. See the documentation starting [here](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/empty-never-throw.html).